# Binding comand for Button

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I have carousel view and bindings properties:

```
<ContentView>
    <controls:CarouselViewControl x:Name="CarouselData" ItemsSource="{Binding StartDisplay}"
                                      ShowIndicators="True"
                                      ShowArrows="False"
                                      IndicatorsTintColor="BurlyWood" CurrentPageIndicatorTintColor="DarkGoldenrod">
        <controls:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Image  Grid.RowSpan="3" Aspect="AspectFill"  Source="{Binding Image}"/>

                    <ContentView Grid.Row="0" Padding="60,30,60,0">
                    </ContentView>

                    <ContentView Grid.Row="1" Padding="20,10,20,50">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Message}"
                                   TextColor="Black"
                                   FontSize="20"
                                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
                    </ContentView>

                    <ContentView Grid.Row="2" Padding="20,10,20,50">
                        <Button Text="Getted start" IsVisible="{Binding VisibleStartButton}"/>
                    </ContentView>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
    </controls:CarouselViewControl>
</ContentView>
```

I pointed *ItemsSource* for CarouselView. 
Class ModelView:

```
public class StartPageViewModel: BaseViewModel // ViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<DataCarouselView> startDisplay;
    public ObservableCollection<DataCarouselView> StartDisplay
    {
        get => startDisplay; set => SetProperty(ref startDisplay, value);
    }

    public StartPageViewModel()
    {
        StartDisplay = new ObservableCollection<DataCarouselView>(new[]
        {
            new DataCarouselView("back_1.png", "test1"),
            new DataCarouselView("back_2.png", "test2"),
            new DataCarouselView("back_3.png", "test3"),
            new DataCarouselView("back_4.png", "test4", true)
        });
        OpenMenuPageCommand = new OpenMenuPageCommand(this);
    }

}
```

class Model:

```
public class DataCarouselView // Model
{
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public bool VisibleStartButton { get; set; }

    public DataCarouselView(string image, string message, bool vis = false)
    {
        Image = image;
        Message = message;
        VisibleStartButton = vis;
    }
}
```

Everything is working.

I want to add command for to the button. I create command class:

```
public class OpenMenuPageCommand : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    private StartPageViewModel viewModel;
    public OpenMenuPageCommand(StartPageViewModel vm)
    {
        viewModel = vm;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return viewModel != null;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (CanExecute(parameter)) 
            viewModel.OpenMenuPage();
    }
}
```

and property in class ViewModel:

```
public ICommand OpenMenuPageCommand { get; }
```

and method command in class ViewModel:

```
public async void OpenMenuPage()
{
    await navigation.PushAsync(new MenuPage());
}
```

How binding command for button? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use relative source binding to make it work

First set the name of your root control as below:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Name="InfoView"
             x:Class="InfoSeries.Views.InfoView">
```

Then you can reference `InfoView` in order to bind `Button` `Command` with your ViewModel:

```
<Button Text="Getted start" IsVisible="{Binding VisibleStartButton}" Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference InfoView}, Path=BindingContext.OpenMenuPageCommand}"/>
```